# why inside function we can override "undefined" but can't in window object in JS...Example is given Below

Tags: javascript

I have given two different code. One inside global `window` object and second inside `foo` function

Here my First code:

```js
var undefined = 2; // 2
console.log(undefined == 2); // it gives me FALSE

var window = 5; // 5
console.log(window == 5); // it gives me FALSE

var a;
console.log(a); // it give me UNDEFINED
```

Here my second code:

```js
function foo() {

  var undefined = 2; // 2
  console.log(undefined == 2); // true

  var window = 5; // 5
  console.log(window == 5); // true

  var a;
  console.log(a);
}
foo();
```

Comment: The second code block returns,
`false`,`true`,`undefined`

Comment: I know its not a good practice but i just wann know what actually happening under the hood of javascript while its execution

Comment: note: `undefined` is often passed as an argument to plugin constructors to ensure that the value is preserved and not redefined. it is really not a thing to do

Comment: @AliSomay he forgot the `var` before undefined, when it is here, undefined gets actually overriden and the results are what he writes

Comment: Google variable shadowing.

Answer (score 3):

`window` and `undefined` are predefined (by the JS engine / browser) variables.

You can't overwrite a read only variable (if a variable already exists, then using `var` in the scope it exists in does nothing).

You can declare a new variable, in a narrower scope, that masks one with the same name in a wider scope.

Answer (score 1):

The global scope won't let you mess with just anything. That would basically cause all sorts of bad things to happen. That's why you can't change the things outside.

Inside the function, in an isolated scope, it'll let you declare variables with other names. While this is an absolutely horrible practice and you should avoid it at all costs, it won't affect anything beyond the one function.

```
function foo() {
    var window = 5;
}
```

The `window` in the function is not the same as the `window` at the global level. The `window` in the function is simply masking the outer window, making it inaccessible from inside of `foo`.

Comment: thnx buddy...i know it is bad practice. i just wann know .Why  it is so.

Answer (score 0):

In Your function `foo() console.log(undefined == 2)`  you mentioned //true is returning. But actually it return "false". Because "undefined" is a reserved keyword. So you can't use this as a variable. See images:
[When using undefined keyword it's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlpV8.png)

Better use some other variable name in your `foo()`
[When using some other variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h01gQ.png)